# What 'this' refers to in following mongoose code?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Following code is from mongoose documentation:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/test');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
// define a schema
var animalSchema = new Schema({name:String, type:String});
// assign a function to the "methods" object of our animalSchema
animalSchema.methods.findSimilarTypes = function(cb){
    return this.model('Animal').find({ type: this.type }, cb);
}
var Animal = mongoose.model('Animal', animalSchema);
var dog = new Animal({ type: 'dog' });

dog.findSimilarTypes(function(err, dogs) {
  console.log(dogs); // woof
});
```

What object first 'this' refers to? Is it 'document' object dog? In API could not find any 'model' method on 'document'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In an instance method, `this` is the instance of the model the method is being called on.

The `Model` class inherits from `Document` and provides the [`model()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model-model) method.

Comment: so the model is called `Animal` . `dog` is the instance of the model. `dog` is also considered a document too if you save it right? I have more questions I just wanted to break it down.

Comment: I'm wondering If you could do `return Animal.find({ type: this.type }, cb);` ? because I'm thinking all the instance of Animal will get that `findSimilarTypes` method and you could do a `.find()` on a model.

Comment: @jackblank Probably best to post that as a new question.